# SSLCACertificateFile returns command not found

Tags: apache, ssl, mod-ssl

I am installing SSL on my domain which is hosted ad digitalocean. I am following this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-an-ssl-certificate-from-a-commercial-certificate-authority). Currently I am trying to do execute commands:

```
SSLCACertificateFile /home/sammy/intermediate.crt
```

and

```
SSLCertificateChainFile /home/sammy/intermediate.crt
```

but both returns me:

```
SSLCACertificateFile: command not found 

SSLCertificateChainFile: command not found
```

errors. I am wondering what I am missing.

Answer (score 4):

These are not commands, you need to put these lines in your config file: httpd.conf